# Php increase upload limit size GODDADY parallel Plesk

Tags: php

newbie question here, I have this GODADDY PLESK hosting and i want to increase its upload limit. I followed all the instruction found in the web. Using .user.ini, it do change the upload limit size but only for the local value and not the master value. [please see link picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC87X.jpg). any suggestion guys? Is there a way that I can change both local and master value?

THANKS in Advance!

Comment: You cant increase it, only your hoster have ability to increase it for you. You can ask them to check this inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with local php.ini but only if server is allowing this. If you don't have dedicated server I think you are unlikely to do this.